# Proof on finitely generated abeilan group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ be distinct non-zero elements of $G$. The following conditions are equivalent:
>   (a) The set $B={x_{1},...,x_{n}}$ is a basis of G.
>   (b) The map $\phi :(r_{1},...,r_{n})\rightarrow r_{1}x_{1}+r_{2}x_{2}+...+r_{n}x_{n}$ is a group isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ to $G$.
>   (c) For each $i$, the map $\chi :r\rightarrow rx_{i}$ is injective and $G=\mathbb{Z}x_{1}\times\mathbb{Z}x_{2}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}x_{n}$

I've already worked out that (a) and (b) are equivlent, and am trying to prove that (a) and (c) are equivalent by proving $(a)\rightarrow (c)$ then $(c)\rightarrow (a)$.

For $(a)\rightarrow (c)$, I know that for $B$ to be the basis of $G$, $ker(\phi)=(0,0,...,0)$, and that $ 0\in ker(\chi)$. Yet how can I then move on to claim that $ker(\chi)=0$? Also any pointers on how to neatly go about the second half of $(c)$? I can intuitively see that $G$ is indeed made up of direct products of $\chi(r_{i}):r_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}$, but to produce a vigorous prove I might need some help.

For $(c)\rightarrow (a)$, similar question arises: how do I go from $ker(\chi)=0$ to draw conclusion that $ker(\phi)=(0,0,...0)$? And a mathmatically sound prove of second part?

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a\to c$

Let $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be the basis, we then know for any element $x$ in $G$ we can write
$$x=\sum_i r_ix_i$$
for some $r_i\in\Bbb Z$, as it is an abelian group. now we define $\chi_i(r)=r x_i$, this is trivial to show to be a homomorphism. However as this is a $\Bbb Z$-module we have that $r x_i$ can only equal to zero if $r=0$ because $x_i$ is already non-zero. So $\chi_i(r)=0\implies r=0$ ergo $\ker \chi_i=0$. For the second part, as you have already $a\implies b$ then your
$$\phi(r_1,\ldots,r_n)=\sum_i \chi_i(r_i)$$ for which the latter follows.

$c\to a$

Let 
$$0=(r_1,\ldots, r_n)$$
We can see that the set of $x_i$ would clearly span all of $G$ but we wish to show that $r_i$ is $0$. Now we define 
$$\varphi:\Bbb Z^n\to \prod_i \Bbb Z x_i$$
by
$$\varphi((r_1,\ldots,r_n))=\prod_i \chi_i(r_i)$$
This one can we see is injective as $\chi_i$ is and it is clearly surjective, and equally clearly a homomorphism, as you already have an isomorphism $\phi$ the rest follows.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The injection part I've figured out just fine, it is the wording of this proposition $G=\mathbb{Z}x_{1}\times\mathbb{Z}x_{2}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}x_{n}$ that drove me nuts when proving it. In my understanding, $G={r_{1}x_{1}+...+r_{n}x_{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ yet it is definitely different from ${\mathbb{Z}x_{1}\times\mathbb{Z}x_{2}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}x_{n}}$. I personally agrees with your interpretation of this direct product here, but I still have my doubts.

Comment: They are different but that doesnt mean the differens is of any importans and as far as we care they are t.